# characterized search using windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a search textbox in my `windows form application` and I want to search character by character means when I write `h` in textbox then shows result in datagridview of `h` and when I add `h` with `a` like `ha` in search textbox then shows result in datagridview of `ha` and its change results in datagridview from `h` to `ha` as same as mobile phone contacts searching. and I working like below:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\Contact.mdf;Integrated Security=True;");
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bindDatagridview();  
        if (textBox1.Text != string.Empty)      
        {      
            search();            
        }
    }
    public void bindDatagridview()
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from contactsinfo", connection);
        da.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        //dataGridView1.DataBindings();
    }
    public void search()
    {
        da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from contactsinfo where ContactName = '" + textBox1.Text + "'", connection);
        da.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        clear();
    }
}
```

But this only work when the form is load and the form is only loaded at first time:
Kindly suggest me what i do, waiting for your reply.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can load all contacts at once, then its simple. On form load get all contacts and save them in `DataView`. Then bind grid to this view:

```
DataView contactsView;

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        var da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM from contactsinfo", conn);
        da.Fill(dt);
    }

    contactsView = dt.AsDataView();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = contactsView;    
}
```

Then just change row filter of `DataView` when text changes in filter TextBox:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    contactsView.RowFilter = 
       String.Format("ContactName LIKE '{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
}
```

If you can't pre-load all data, then you should use same `TextChanged` event to query for filtered data.

NOTE: You should handle `'` in user input.

Comment: Its not working fine and I am getting exception                 `Field 'search.Form2.contactsView' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null` at this line `DataView contactsView;`

Comment: @user88 please read sample carefully. There is `contactsView` initialization just before binding of the grid